# handle go back in initialRoute for deeplinking in react native nested stack

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deep-linking

i'm trying to implement deep link in react native project now what i want is when a user opens app via deeplink it will be redirected to the specific page and then once he presses back he should go to HomeScreen now this perfectly works fine  when i open CommentsScreen or PodcastDetailScreen via deep link but when i open up BlogLikesUserListScreen or ManageConnectionsScreen it oepns though when i click on harware back button it exits the app how should i write the config for linking so that when i open BlogLikesUserListScreen via deeplink and press back button it should go to HomeScreen ?
i tried various combinations but i failed

```
const App = () => { 
return(
<NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
  <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="SplashScreen"
    screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
    <Stack.Screen name="AppScreens" component={AppScreens} />

    <Stack.Screen name="ModalScreens" component={ModalScreens} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>;
)

function AppScreens({navigation}) {
  return (
    <TabBar.Navigator initialRouteName={'NetworkTabBar'}>
      <TabBar.Screen name="NetworkTabBar" component={NetworkNavigator} />
    </TabBar.Navigator>
  );
}

function NetworkNavigator() {
  return (
    <NetworkBar.Navigator>
      <NetworkBar.Screen name="HomeScreens" component={HomeScreens} />
      <NetworkBar.Screen name="PodcastScreens" component={PodcastScreens} />
    </NetworkBar.Navigator>
  );
}

function HomeScreens({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="CommentsScreen" component={CommentsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
function ModalScreens() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="BlogLikesUserListScreen"
        component={BlogLikesUserListScreen}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

// configuration for deep_link

const config = {
  screens: {
    AppScreens: {
      screens: {
        NetworkTabBar: {
          screens: {
            HomeScreens: {
              initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
              screens: {
                CommentsScreen: 'social/blog/details/:blogId/',
              },
            },
            PodcastScreens: {
              initialRouteName: 'PodcastListScreen',
              screens: {
                PodcastDetailScreen: 'podcast/:podcastId/',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    ModalScreens: {
      initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
      screens: {
        ManageConnectionsScreen: {
          initialRouteName: 'FindConnectionsScreen',
          screens: {
            ManageConnectionsScreen: 'social/connected/:type/',
          },
        },
        BlogLikesUserListScreen: {
          initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
          screens: {
            BlogLikesUserListScreen: 'social/blog/likes/:blog_id',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
}
```

Comment: This has already happened to me and I tried many combinations, what helped me to get out of place was to use the flipper with the react navigation plugin and put the path there. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/devtools/ try to have a look. Then use the linking tab to test the deep linking path you are calling.